# How can I destroy session token after Sign Out?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to have a different token of the session after every Sign-Out. Or how I can protect user session via Devise gem if intruder will steal my user's session?

Comment: so whats the problem `I want to have a different token of the session after every Sign-Out`, what do you mean by that `if intruder will steal my user's session?`

Comment: Be more descriptive while asking question.